# Track bandwith usage by application

Tags: windows, cloud, rackspace, security

I have a server at Rackspace and noticed my server is suddenly sending out 2GB of data per month (this is atypical since I don't use it that much)

How can I figure out what application is using that bandwith and who is consuming it?

I suppose it would also be beneficial to see how much data is incoming too...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a stand-alone light-weight [SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com) tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can suit your needs.
Network activity is just one of the many events that this tool can monitor/filter/highlight/…